# Oracle can't read arabic digit

Tags: oracle, arabic

My system using NLS_LANG = AR8MSWIN1256

This character set most read arabic character.

But, only arabic digit can't read.

ex) ٠ ١ ٢ ٣ ٤ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩

These auto-convet into question marks to DB.

oracle column dump text

[ Typ=1 Len=1: 63 ]

I tried below things.

- Change NLS_LANG = AL32UTF8
- Change Regedit Oralce NLS_LANG = AL32UTF8

But, didn't works.

Please give me any solutions.

Comment: Which client application do you use?

Comment: `NLS_LANG = AR8MSWIN1256` is not valid. Try `NLS_LANG = .AR8MSWIN1256` (with a dot)